# AND operator is returning no results in elastic search script

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have one field which contains 2-3 items in one string.
suppose the field is :

```
       "target" : "one two three"
```

Now below is my script:

```
       {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['target'].value != null && (doc['target'].value.contains('one') || doc['target'].value.contains('two'))"
            }
          }
        }
```

I am getting the correct result with the above script, Now If I want to get those records in which the target field has both items- "one" and "two", So I wrote below script just by changing the operator to AND(&&).

```
       {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['target'].value != null && (doc['target'].value.contains('one') && doc['target'].value.contains('two'))"
            }
          }
        }
```

But now, I am getting no results. I am not getting what is the problem here. Please help.

Comment: Not an elastics search expert, but I guess this should work as you describe. Yet you could probably leave away the parentheses after the first &&.

Comment: I have tried by removing the extra parenthesis as well, but didn't get the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you break your statement into two:

```
{
  "script": {
      "script": {
           "inline": "doc['target'].value != null && (doc['target'].value.contains('one'); doc['target'].value != null && doc['target'].value.contains('two'))"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach, but its working as OR,  :(